# Nextjs13 Google Maps Pinch to zoom

Tags: google-maps, maps, next.js13, pinchzoom

I have a NextJs 13 app and I've added Google Maps (using @react-google-maps/api, also tried with api from google, @googlemaps/js-api-loader).

No special settings are made just:
`center: { lat: initialLat, lng: initialLng }, zoom: 13,`

Everything works fine, the map is displayed, but I don't have that pinch-to-zoom effect that is on maps.google.com for smooth zoom (not the zoom from + / - buttons).

There is no css or js that rewrite something.

Is there any way to enable the pinch-to-zoom?
Also, is there any possibility to zoom so the map to be at a specific dimension (for example, at zoom 13 the map has 7km displayed in width and I want to change the zoom to have 8km displayed)?

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the lack of feature that you have mentioned? From what I know, react-google-maps/api uses Maps Javascript API which have the pinch-to-zoom effect when on mobile.

Comment: See this sample in the official documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple